# {14.04} No boot graphics (Not a problem just annoying)

Tags: 14.04, boot, graphics

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and when i boot, the bootloader graphics dont show. I am using the proprietary Nvidia drivers so i can edit videos. This isnt a big problem, its just annoying.

Comment: See the above, the boot splash does not work with the nvidia driver =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>c</kbd> on grub to get in the console and then enter `videoinfo`.

Note down the highest resolution and color depth available. E.g `1920x1080x32`.
Load ubuntu and enter in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and add the following:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32    
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

(Add your own resolution and color depth). Save it, exit and enter in the terminal:

```
echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```